# "It is 50 square meters" or "It is 50 meters square"?

Tags: word-usage

Which one is correct?

"It is 50 square meters" or "It is 50 meters square"?

Google "50 square meters"-->600k

Google "50 meters square" --> 6k

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A rectangle measuring 5 metres by 10 metres has an area of *50 square metres*.

A square with sides of 50 metres is said to be *50 metres squared* (or *50 metres square*) and has an area of 2,500 square metres.

Comment: Corrected - it should be 50 metres squared.

Comment: People do use the phrase '*n* metres square' to mean a square with sides whose length is *n*.  https://books.google.com/books?id=9NXS0KGMiuAC&pg=PA134&dq=%22metres+square%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjpif7-xa_PAhXBVj4KHR4RDewQ6AEIejAR#v=onepage&q=%22metres%20square%22&f=false

Comment: See also https://books.google.com/books?id=XnAEiEaSPikC&pg=PA799&dq=%22metres+square%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNia-Fx6_PAhXENz4KHZFJCJM4FBDoAQhLMAk#v=onepage&q=%22metres%20square%22&f=false

Answer (score -1):

## You should say "50 square metres".

"50 metres square[d]" is ambiguous. Do you mean it is a square that is 50 metres on a side (so its area is 2500 m²)? Or do you mean it has an area of 50 m²? I have encountered both usages, and both are defensible:

- "50 metres squared" is a description of a calculation: it's a length of 50 metres, squared.
- "50 metres squared" is a reading of the symbols in "50 m²" in the same order as written.

Hence you should not use this phrasing, no matter which one you meant. Instead, say "square metres" (or "a square 50 metres on a side" on the odd occasion that you want to describe exactly that).

**Source:** I'm a maths teacher.

Comment: Please don't **shout** your personal preferences. The form may be ambiguous, and it's fine to suggest avoiding it. But this is language, not maths, and we cope with ambiguity all the time.

Comment: @ColinFine: We do indeed deal with ambiguity all the time. Sometimes we embrace it: puns, irony, wordplay of all forms. Sometimes it just gets in our way, though, and I think this is one of those cases. I'm sorry that I seemed to be shouting. If you meant my heading, I put it as a heading because *I* find it helpful to see a short answer like that, so I do the same in my answers. If you meant my "Source" line, I didn't mean to suggest that this *is* maths. I just thought my having extensive experience with this *exact* question was odd, and called for some explanation.