# How many square meters "twenty feet square" is?

Tags: measure-expressions, numerals

One would assume it to be about 2 square meters, but this is obviously not the case. In fact, I'm reading Illium by Dan Simmons. A quote follows:

> Much like the room they had faxed into, this space was windowless and **about twenty feet square**. But unlike the other room, this one was warm, lighted, and free of snow or ice. And unlike the other room, this one was **almost filled with an oval metal machine about fifteen feet long**.

By this description, "twenty feet square" seems to mean 20x20 feet aka 400 square feet or 40 square meters. Given that Dan Simmons is a renowned American writer, it's not likely that he just can't speak English correctly. So, who's right and who's wrong here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["It is 50 square meters" or "It is 50 meters square"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/104845/it-is-50-square-meters-or-it-is-50-meters-square)

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is a duplicate, but the answers there are pretty dreadful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*20 square feet* is a measure of area: for instance, an object 4 feet by 5 feet.

*20 feet square* is a measure of linear dimensions: a square 20 feet on each side.

A room '20 feet square' has an area of 400 square feet, or between 10 and 11 square meters.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just one question: Is this distinction specific to the US or is it a thing one would hear in England too?

Comment: @user60294: As I expected to find, this question has been raised before both on ELL and [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/403938/). I believe *all* native Anglophones would make the same distinction. We all need to disambiguate the two senses, and the position of the adjective is the obvious candidate for an "indicator of intended sense". It would stick out like a sore thumb if any individual or dialectal group used them the other way round to the established "standard". A standard which I believe is inherently more syntactically "logical" in any case.

Comment: @ I see, thanks. I've been using wordings like "twenty by twenty" when speaking English for decades without a single eyebrow risen, but maybe native speakers were just being kind to me. :)

Comment: @user60294 "Twenty by twenty" is fine, too.